# Android navigation drawer (when clicked) is triggering my OnItemSelectedListener for a spinner in my toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, onitemselectedlistener

I currently have a Fragment hosted by an activity (which extends AppCompatActivity) layout. This parent activity sets a Navigation Drawer. The activity layout has a `Toolbar` which hosts a `Spinner` from the Fragment, which is created (inflated) via the Fragments `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.

In the `onCreateOptionsMenu`, I set an `OnItemSelectedListener` to the spinner which handles the selected value (which then updates the fragment). The problem I am facing though, is in the fragment (or perhaps the activity?): **When I click the Navigation Drawer (toggle icon), this invokes the `OnItemSelectedListener`, which is not what I want.** The code is working well handling the spinner in the menu, but I want to remove the `OnItemSelectedListener` response to the Navigation Drawer being clicked (it is currently creating a FragmentTransaction from the aforementioned `OnItemSelectedListener` method). The listener is even being triggered when I swipe in the Navigation Drawer and not even clicking the drawer toggle.

**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, 
            View view, int position, long l) {
            // Code to run when the item gets clicked
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        // Populate the list view
        drawers = new Drawer["A", "B", "C"]
        drawerList.setAdapter(new DrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_drawer, drawers));
        drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        // Display the correct fragment
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            currentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
            //setActionBarTitle(currentPosition);
        } else {
            selectItem(0);
        }
        // Create the ActionBarDrawerToggle
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
                R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer) {
            // Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed stated
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            // Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    }
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.spinner_menu, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
        spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String
            (getActivity(), R.layout.spinner, spinnerTitle);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id)
            {
                if (setNavigation) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item : " + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Fragment fragment;
                    if (position != 0) {
                        fragment = ExampleFragment.newInstance();
                    } else {
                        fragment = new ExampleFragment();
                    }

                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "visible_fragment");
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    ft.commit();
                } else {
                    setNavigation = !setNavigation;
                }
            }// to close the onItemSelected
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {

            }
        });

    }
```

**Inflate Menu XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:title="ActionBar Spinner"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        android:background="#ff00"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the spinner is overlaping with the drawer button space, so when you try to touch the home button to open the drawer, you must be activating the spinner listener instead. I'm just guessing, so far there is no other error that I can spot. Hope it helps!

Comment: When you say "click the Navigation Drawer", do you mean clicking an item within the drawer itself, or clicking the toggle that opens and closes it?

Comment: Clicking the toggle that opens and closes it. @JonathanAste: I thought that too, but I have clicked the surrounding space of the toolbar and this does not trigger the listener. Plus the spinner is added as a menu item (therefor exempt from setting width and height). Added info: it is even being triggered when I swipe in the Navigation Drawer.

Comment: What is the view that gets passed into the onItemSelected method when you open the drawer?

Comment: It's the `invalidateOptionsMenu()` calls you have in the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` overrides. Do you really need those, or are they just leftover from an example you followed?

Comment: @Charlie android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{d1157a7 V.ED..... ........ 0,0-230,89} Having looked at the API for AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, it seems as though the conflict is from the shared view of the toolbar. I call the `invalidateOptionsMenu()` because some hosted fragments have their own menu items to be added.

Comment: Those menus load during the transactions. You don't need to invalidate when the drawer opens/closes.

Comment: @MikeM. You have identified the problem! I have just commented out this code and it is working well! I thought the `invalidateOptionsMenu()` method ensured that a new hosted fragment would load its menu item? But since I have commented it out, the hosting fragment is still loading the spinner perfectly...

Comment: I put my comments into an answer, so you can close out your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The `onDrawerOpened()` and `onDrawerClosed()` overrides on the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` are calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()`, which is recreating the options menu, and firing your `Spinner`'s `OnItemSelectedListener` each time the drawer opens or closes. It looks like you've got a `boolean` flag setup to ignore the listener firing immediately after the `Spinner` initialization, but after that menu has been created the first time, the flag has already been set, and each time the menu is recreated after that, your `FragmentTransaction` is running.

You can simply remove those calls, as the menu creation is handled sufficiently during the `FragmentTransaction`s. You'd only really need to invalidate the menu if something in it needs to change after it's already been created. If that's all you were using the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` overrides for, you can just remove those altogether.